# Group by numbers that are in sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I have some data like this:

```
row    id
1      1
2      36
3      37
4      38
5      50
6      51
```

I would like to query it to look like this:

```
 row    id    group
 1      1     1
 2      36    2
 3      37    2
 4      38    2
 5      50    3
 6      51    3
```

... so that I can GROUP BY where the numbers are consecutively sequential.

Also, looping/cursoring is out of the question since I'm working with a pretty large set of data, thanks.

Comment: How do you determine which rows belongs to a specific group?

Comment: From the data, when the next value is sequential to the last value, its in the same group, otherwise the group increases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table #temp
(
    IDUnique int Identity(1,1),
    ID int, 
    grp int
)


Insert into #temp(ID) Values(1)
Insert into #temp(ID) Values(36)
Insert into #temp(ID) Values(37)
Insert into #temp(ID) Values(38)
Insert into #temp(ID) Values(50)
Insert into #temp(ID) Values(51)

declare @IDUnique int
declare @PreviousUnique int
declare @ID int
declare @grp int
declare @Previous int
declare @Row int

DECLARE @getAccountID CURSOR SET @getAccountID = CURSOR FOR SELECT Row_Number() Over(Order by IDUnique) Row, IDUnique, ID  From #temp
OPEN @getAccountID
FETCH NEXT FROM @getAccountID INTO @Row, @IDUnique, @ID 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    IF(@Row = 1)
    Begin
        update #temp set grp = 1 Where IDUnique = @IDUnique
        set @Previous = @ID
        set @grp = 1
    End
    Else If (@Previous + 1 = @ID)
    Begin
        update #temp set grp = @grp Where IDUnique = @IDUnique
        set @Previous = @ID
    End
    Else
    Begin
        set @Previous = @ID
        set @grp = @grp + 1
        update #temp set grp = @grp Where IDUnique = @IDUnique
    End
    FETCH NEXT FROM @getAccountID INTO @Row, @IDUnique, @ID
END
CLOSE @getAccountID
DEALLOCATE @getAccountID

Select * from #temp
Drop Table #temp
```

Comment: This one actually ended up being the fastest. Go figure.

Comment: @Gagege You said looping/cursoring was out of question, so we didn't try ;)

Comment: @GSerg I thought it was going to be too slow. My apologies! I have learned a ton about SQL this week.

Answer (score 4):

```
;WITH firstrows AS
(
    SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) groupid
    FROM Table1 a
    WHERE id - 1 NOT IN (SELECT b.id FROM Table1 b)
)
SELECT id, 
    (
        SELECT MAX(b.groupid)
        FROM firstrows b
        WHERE b.id <= a.id
    ) groupid
FROM Table1 a
```

Comment: Love your solution!
I'd rather use `lag` for finding the previous id and then filter out values if `prev is null or (id - prev) > 1`

Answer (score 4):

```
with
  data(row, id) as (
    select * 
    from (
      values
       (1,1)
      ,(2,36)
      ,(3,37)
      ,(4,38)
      ,(5,50)
      ,(6,51)
    ) as foo(row, id)
  ),
  anchor(row, id) as (
    select row, id
    from data d1
    where not exists(select 0 from data d2 where d2.id = d1.id - 1)
  )
select d1.*, dense_rank() over(order by foo.id) as thegroup
from
  data d1
  cross apply (select max(id) from anchor where anchor.id <= d1.id) as foo(id)
order by
  d1.row
  ;
```

Comment: Hmmm... When executed in a batch, the three queries ([1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536780/group-by-numbers-that-are-in-sequence/6537054#6537054),[2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536780/group-by-numbers-that-are-in-sequence/6537036#6537036),[3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536780/group-by-numbers-that-are-in-sequence/6537034#6537034)) can be accounted for 14 / 46 / 41 percent of execution expenses, respectively. This one is the cheapest ;)

Comment: This give you the ID's, but does it GROUP?

Comment: @FlyingStreudel This gives group IDs to group upon. The trick is to figure them, actual subsequent grouping is trivial. Look at the other answers.

Comment: If it's that much faster I'll probably end up using this one. I'm trying it on my data now.

Comment: Interesting, when I run [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536780/group-by-numbers-that-are-in-sequence/6537054#6537054) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536780/group-by-numbers-that-are-in-sequence/6537034#6537034) in a batch with my data, yours accounts for only 6% of the relative cost. But, the two queries take almost the same amount of time. Yours is only about 10 seconds faster with the total time being about 1 minute 40 seconds. Why is that?

Comment: @Gagege I didn't say mine was faster, I said it was cheaper ;) The optimizer strives for cost, not speed. Speed is related to cost, but how exactly it is related to cost is a rather good question to ask. Sometimes the cheapest execution plan is about 50 times slower than a more expensive one, in which case you have to be creative in forcing the server to use the plan you need, not the plan it wants.

Comment: @GSerg Ok, I'll need to learn more about that. I am still using your solution since it's faster. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This solution does more work that is strictly necessary on the basis that there may be gaps in the sequence of `row` values, and on the assumption that those gaps should be ignored.

Set up test data:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
(ROW INT,
id INT
)

INSERT @table
SELECT 1,1
UNION SELECT 2,36
UNION SELECT 3,37
UNION SELECT 4,38
UNION SELECT 5,50
UNION SELECT 6,51
```

Output query

```
;WITH grpCTE
AS
(
    SELECT ROW, id,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ROW
                        ) AS rn
    FROM @table
)
,recCTE
AS
(
    SELECT ROW, id, rn, 1 AS grp
    FROM grpCTE
    WHERE rn = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT g.row, g.id, g.rn, CASE WHEN g.id = r.id + 1 THEN r.grp ELSE r.grp + 1 END AS grp
    FROM grpCTE AS g
    JOIN recCTE AS r
    ON g.rn = r.rn + 1
)
SELECT row, id, grp FROM recCTE
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Select T.Id, T.Row, groupId as "Group", dr  FROM tbrows T
Left Outer Join
    (
    Select min(id) as groupId,DENSE_RANK() over( order by min(id)) as dr, MIN(row-id) as d, Sum(1) as s FROM tbrows
         Group BY (row-id)
    ) U
On (T.Id >= U.groupId) and (T.Id < U.groupId+U.s)
Order By T.Id
```

Comment: i've modified the join condition; it DOES work now, check it out